# Does an expired Exchange password block other email accounts and text messaging?

Tags: exchange

I use the Exchange email client on my Lumia 640 to access work emails. Yesterday I had to change my network password because it was expiring. Prior to updating the password on the phone, I was unable to access gmail and Outlook email on the phone and text messages were not sent. I didn't realize there was a problem until this morning and after restarting the phone I received the notification that I had to update my Exchange password.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Is your Exchange account the primary account for the phone?

Comment: No, my personal Microsoft account is the account I used to set up the phone. I added the Exchange account much later since I've been reluctant to get work emails on a personal phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the behaviour I've experienced with Windows Phone 8.x (or 7.x), and my non-Exchange accounts merrily continue to synchronise when my work Exchange account has its password expire.